# Чем посмотреть порты которые занимает программа

Tags: веб-сервер, порты, сканирование-портов

У меня есть софт которому требуются открытые в интернет порты.
Сервер в локальной сети. Сейчас они закрыты, мне нужно запустить программу и посмотреть какие она пытается занять порты. Посоветуйте что-нибудь.
Как вы понимаете сейчас нужные мне порты закрыты и например nmap их не детектит, он видить только подключенные. Или может быть есть какая-то опция ? помогите!

Comment: Может команда: netstat -ntulp поможет, ну и если порты закрыты то их ни одна прога не увидит.

Comment: Поставьте фаервол, и мониторьте. Из извесных: Agnitum outpost (фаервол), Wireshark (монитор сети).

Comment: @VladVetrov netstat -ntulp тоже показывает только открытые tcp и udp подключения,

Comment: Если нужны закрытые порты то вот 0 - 65536 выбирайте любой, исключая то что показал netstat -ntulp

Comment: @VladVetrov, да нет, в принципе другая задача. Вы не знаете какие порты нужно пробросить наружу, nmap показывает только открытые, на компьютере софт который занимает какие-то , как узнать какие? чтобы их пробросить

Comment: @VladVetrov вообще nmap может и закрытые показывать, просто задача понять какие порты хочет занять определённая программа, если скажем толком по этому софту документации нет.

Comment: Запустил программу, на этом же компе запустил netstat -ntulp, увидел что открыт порт такой-то. Все нет проблем